# insert comma between two quotation mark using gsub

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to insert a comma between two phrases that are delimited by a quotation mark. I'm usually able to do it using `gsub("\"", ",",my_string)` but for some reason, in this case, it's not working.

printing my object results in

```
"the teaching approach that you used during the class" "the way you answered to student's questions"
```

I need to insert a comma into a series of expression that might contain two or more phrases. In this case, the desired output would be

```
the teaching approach that you used during the class, the way you answered to student's questions
```

EDIT:

To be specific: the object as suggested in the comments is a vector of length 2. I transformed it in a single vector and used gsub as indicated.

any help is appreciated

Comment: what is the input to gsub that resulted in that output

Comment: Aren't you looking for paste(., sep = ",")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are a vector of `length` 2.  We concatenate those with `paste` (`toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=", ")`

```
toString(str1)
```

---

If it is a single string

```
gsub('" +"', ", ", mystring)
#[1] "the teaching approach that you used during the class, the way you answered to student's questions"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("the teaching approach that you used during the class", 
    "the way you answered to student's questions" )
mystring <- 'the teaching approach that you used during the class" "the way you answered to student\'s questions'
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have realized that answer to this question is very simple, but creating that sample `mystring` mentioned by `OP` is difficult. Surely it will provide learning opportunity to new users of `R`.

```
# How to create that sample mystring?
# Start with single quotes (') and end with single quotes ('). 
# Make a note: There is single quotes as student's. Hence you need 
# escape character before ' in student's.
mystring <- 'the teaching approach that you used during the class" "the way you answered to student\'s questions'

#Check if mystring matches with that of OP
cat(mystring)
# the teaching approach that you used during the class" "the way you answered to student's questions
```

Answer:

```
gsub('(\\"\\s+\\")',", ",mystring)
[1] "the teaching approach that you used during the class, the way you answered to student's questions"
```

**Regex:** Look for `"` separate by only space. If found then replace with ", ".